# Type C to type C USB2.0

Tags: usb

Is is possible to make a keyboard cable using [these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002305151277.html?spm=a2g0s.8937460.0.0.188d2e0eWHaH1k) connectors and only 4 core wire?  I have made many type c to type A leads with 4 core cable, but is it possible with Type C to Type C?  It only has to be USB2.0 and for use with a keyboard device.

Comment: Is there any data on those connectors? If not, then it can't be known

Answer (score 1):

USB2-only Type-C to Type-C cable is normative (Table 3-11, p. 76 of [USB Type-C cable and Connector Specification 2.0](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf#page=76)). It requires 5 wires (GND, VBUS, D+, D-, CC) plus shield.

Connectors you are pointing at are unclear in terms of functionality and pinout, but 4-wire cable kills the project anyhow.

If you want this cable used only by a given device, you may make it a captive plug attached to keyboard (like most keyboards on the market). Then you may have configuration resistors (Rd/Ra on CC1/CC2) mounted on the paddle card on the plug-side of the cable and use a 4-wire cable construction between the Type-C plug and keyboard.